# How to get dispayfield in extjs combo?

Tags: extjs

In extjs combobox, we have `valueField, displayField`. There is one `getValue().` But there is no `getDisaplay().` So how to capture the name of the dispay field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the value to get the record out of the store, and get the display value from there.

Abstractly, you can use this code, but you might substitute some of the variables for known values to make it more readable:

```
getComboDisplay = function(combo) {
    var value = combo.getValue();
    var valueField = combo.valueField;
    var record;
    combo.getStore().each(function(r){
        if(r.data[valueField] == value){
            record = r;
            return false;
        }
    });

    return record ? record.get(combo.displayField) : null;
}
```

Comment: OP should accept the answer from @Dasha_Salo, it is simpler than mine, and appears to work the same.

Comment: this answer is too complicated. OP, please check @Dasha answer

Answer (score 15):

What about getRawValue method?

```
Ext.getCmp('combo').getRawValue();
```

Comment: this is the answer

Answer (score 1):

an easy solution that worket for me :

```
comboselect: function (combo,record) {
    alert(combo.rawValue);
}
```

hope that help you

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJS 4 there is a built-in `findRecord()` method that does the searching that BigSean suggested above, so you don't have to write all that code:

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.field.ComboBox, {
    getDisplayedValue: function() {     // getDisplayValue() already exists but is a private method
        var me = this,
            value = me.value,
            record = null;
        if(value) {
            record = me.getStore().findRecord(me.valueField, value);
        }
        if(record) {
            return record.get(me.displayField);
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```